# Increasing arc effect with HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, automatic-ref-counting

I don't know if there's a name for this effect but is basically an arc that increases and becomes a circle in the end.

I hope this image gives you an idea.
[image]

Basically I need to create an arc of which length I can change through JavaScript (keeping the same radius). I would really want to try doing this with divs and border radius (playing with width, height, left, top, border-radius.

So, in order to achieve a 90 degrees arc like in (1) I would use this:

```
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
```

Yet, the arc would start with a single pixel then increasing will become (1), then (2), (3) and finally a complete circle. One of the problems I have is that the border is not a rigid solid border but something like this:

[image]

The border loose its color strength to the ends of the arc and that would be the first issue I don't know how to fix. Secondly, do you know some algorithm that plays with size, position and border-radius that would help you create an arc with a specified size and radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using a canvas and simple JS.

JS

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
//ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI); //Full circle
//ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,1.5*Math.PI); //3/4 circle
//ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,Math.PI); //Half circle
ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,0.5*Math.PI); //1/4 circle
ctx.stroke();
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r3CSS/

Syntax for .arc is : .arc(x-coordinate , y-coordinate , radius, start Angle, end Angle[, counterclockwise]);

Comment: I know. I could use this and VML arc in IE8 and below, but what about non-IE browsers that don't support canvas (<Firefox 21.0, <Chrome 27.0, <Safari 5.1, <Opera 16.0)?

Comment: You can use the excanvas.js. It has hits on performance a bit in older browsers, but not many people use them nowdays anyways. So if that doesn't bother you the source code is here: http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/source/browse/trunk/silverlight/excanvas.js?r=48 Just download/save it and add it in as a header script.